# Show song's album art/cover art in the notification bar

Tags: javascript, html, audio, spotify, audio-player

I am making an online music player and tackled a serious problem. I want to show the song title (audio, format - mp3), singer's names and the album art in the notification panel on both mobile and pc devices. I pulled out showing the song's title by replacing it dynamically with the webpage's title and that works. But one of the main things the album art and the singer's name, I was not able to make that work.

Also I searched the whole internet for a workaround but was unsuccessful. Spotify shows the the album art beside the song title and the singer's names are shown below the song title on pc/laptops but on mobile devices only the song title is displayed. Whereas YouTube music displays everything on all devices. I am attaching notification panel photos for reference. Here are the two -

1.[YouTube music on mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gs3Z.png)

2.[Spotify On PCs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHeQn.png)

I know this can be achieved by JavaScript notification api, but Spotify and YouTube music does that without asking for the notification request or permission whatever you can say. So don't recommend that idea please.